# How do I do a double transposition in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

Please can you help me take my data from this:

```
Name   + Class   + Teacher
-------+---------+-----------
Fred   + Chem    + Mr Blond
Fred   + Chem    + Mr Pink
Fred   + Maths   + Mr Blond
Barney + Chem    + Mr Brown
Barney + French  + Mr Black
Barney + French  + Mr Blond
```

to this:

```
Name   + Class1  + Teacher1_1 + Teacher1_2 + Class2  + Teacher2_1 + Teacher2_2
-------+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------
Fred   + Chem    + Mr Blond   + Mr Pink    + Maths   + Mr Blond   +
Barney + Chem    + Mr Brown   +            + French  + Mr Black   + Mr Blond
```

So basically one observation per student, with classes transposed per student and teachers transposed per student-class, but interleaved with the classes.

I'm not sure whether this is a double PROC TRANSPOSE operation or something else. I've come across something using PROC SUMMARY, but I'm less familiar with that. It may be a manual DATA step thing, but I'm really at a loss.

Thank you.

Comment: I should add that I'm not too bothered with the naming convention I've used for the columns above. It would perhaps be better to have Name | Class1 | Class1_Teacher1 | Class1_Teacher2 | Class2 | Class2_Teacher1 | Class2_Teacher2. It's the structure that I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as pie.  First you output to a vertical format, then transpose.  The only tricky part for this compared to normal double transposing is your class/teacher combinations aren't unique so you have to add in some extra logic - normally an array would work better for that, but not in this case.

```
data have;
input Name  $  Class  $  Teacher $;
datalines;
Fred    Chem     MrBlond
Fred    Chem     MrPink
Fred    Maths    MrBlond
Barney  Chem     MrBrown
Barney  French   MrBlack
Barney  French   MrBlond
;;;;
run;

data have_pret;
set have;
array transvars[2] class teacher;
by name class notsorted;
if first.name then counter=0;
if first.class then do;
    class_counter=0;
    counter+1;
    id=cats('Class',counter);
    value=class;
    output;
end;
class_counter+1;
id=cats('Teacher',counter,'_',class_counter);
value=teacher;
output;
run;

proc transpose data=have_pret out=want;
by name notsorted;
id id;
var value;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's done the trick. I've done a minor change to the id line to create the format I mentioned in my added comment above, and it's perfect now. I don't really know much about SAS arrays, so this would never have been something I would have looked at. Always something to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not actually using an array there; I originally did and then decided not to, just forgot to remove the array statement :)  Array works well for the simple case, but not in your case where you don't exactly want one for one transposition.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this @Joe. Would you mind sharing with me how this would be done using an array, i.e. for the simpler case? I've tried, but really can't get on with arrays.

Comment: Basically what you do is iterate over the array, and grab the `VNAME` and value from the array.  `do _t = 1 to dim(yourarray); varname = vname(yourarray[_t]); value = yourarray[_t]; output; end;` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone else can come up with a more elegant solution, but this should work....

```
    proc sort
        data=dataset;
        by name;
    run;

    proc transpose 
        data=dataset
        out=dataset;
        var Class Teacher;
        by Name;
    run;

    DATA teacher_dataset class_dataset;
        set dataset;
        if  _NAME_ = "Teacher"  then  output teacher_dataset;
        else if _NAME_ = "Class"    then  output class_dataset;

    run;


    PROC SQL;
        create table final_dataset as
        select 
                a.Name,
                b.Col1 as Class1,
                a.Col1 as Teacher1,
                b.Col2 as Class2,
                a.Col2 as Teacher2,
                b.Col3 as Class3,
                a.Col3 as Teacher3

        from        teacher_dataset as a
        left join   class_dataset   as b
            on a.Name=b.Name;
    quit;
```

Comment: Actually re-reading the question what I responded with is not exactly what you were looking to do, but I think this gets you pretty close...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, it didn't quite get me there, but it's given me some useful techniques for the future.